# Efficiency of interactive versus non-interactive zero-knowledge proofs?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Some projects (e.g., https://zkpass.org/) are claiming that interactive ZKPs can be more efficient than non-interactive ZKPs. What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: Can you describe or provide a link to the specific claim? The website you linked isn't very user-friendly.

Comment: I'm the wrong person to give a full answer, but part of it is that attackers are more constrained in the setting of interactive proofs. See for example [section 5.3.1 of Thaler's *Proofs, Arguments, and Zero-Knowledge*](https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.pdf). This can be used to justify smaller parameters for interactive proofs.

Comment: @lamontap They have a white paper under the "Resources" tab. You can see their benchmark comparison in Section 5. If I understand correctly, they achieve their performance gain through usage of Interactive Commit and Prove Zero-Knowledge Proofs (ICP-ZKP, see section 1.3 and 4). Is this plausible?

Comment: @MarkSchultz-Wu That argument definitely seems plausible and valid 

Comment: I am not sure if this is what zkpass refers to but, another aspect of efficient is the communication complexity. For a SIGMA protocol the interactive version requires a 1.5 round trip of communication. With that comes all sorts of overhead to achieve that communication. In non-interactive version only incurs a single _protocol message_. For an online application this is much more efficient.

Comment: @MarcIlunga They are actually claiming the opposite: Because they are using interaction, they can be more efficient. I don't understand the full details yet, but they say that they can thereby get away with less memory, because they can break up the circuits into smaller parts ‍♂️ (Memory is often a bottle neck when running a ZK prover in constrained environments such as web browsers.) That alone however doesn't explain how they achieve much better running times as well.

Comment: @mti, sorry I misread the question. After reading a bit over their documentation, my understanding is that they are describing a situation where currently zk-snarks can't handle huge circuits. Considering PLONK for instance, the computation is encoded as a polynomial of degree linear in the number of constraints. Add in the overhead of the FFT computation needed to interpolate the computation trace and this becomes quite prohibitive. Some benchmarks report using 6M constraints to implement SHA256.

Comment: In contrast zkpass seems to rely on proof systems based on Vector Oblivous Linear Evaluation (VOLE). I am not very familiar with this line of work but my understanding is that basically, VOLE is used to create homomorphic commitments. Then the prover uses the homomorphic properties of the commitment scheme to evaluate the circuit gate by gate (in ZK) while proving consistency. Which eliminates the need to store the entire computation trace/constraints. The downside is a potentially larger proof size, at least for a naïve protocol.